# Having trouble using in my CLI to display information recieved from an API

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I am creating a CLI and I have the basic functionality working but on my second layer when it is supposed to display info about an object that was pulled from an API I am getting a variable/method error I am wondering if this is because there is a disconnect once the object is selected there is no pokemon key to display inside the pokemon's hash?

Below is the error then the API file followed by the method/variable in question.

`` PokeDEX-CLI/lib/PokeDEX_CLI/cli.rb:47:in `sub_menu_input': undefined local variable or method `pokemon' for #<PokeDEXCLI::CLI:0x00007f9d14424f88> (NameError)
Did you mean?  list_pokemon ``

```
    BASE_URL = "https://pokeapi.co"

    def self.get_all_pokemon(page=nil)
        if page
            response = RestClient.get(page)
        else 
            response = RestClient.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151")
        end
        pokemon_array = JSON.parse(response.body)["results"]
#binding.pry
        pokemon_array.each do |pokemon|
            PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon.new(pokemon)
        end
    end


end 

    def sub_menu_input
        user_input = gets.strip

        if user_input.to_i.between?(1, PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon.all.length)
          character = PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon.all[user_input.to_i - 1]
          print_pokemon_details(pokemon)
          continue?
        elsif user_input.downcase == "exit"
          goodbye
        else
          invalid_choice
          sub_menu_options
        end
      end

      def print_pokemon_details(pokemon)
        puts "Name: #{pokemon.name}"
        puts "Number: #{pokemon.id}"
        puts "Types: #{pokemon.types}"
      end
```

Comment: There's nothing called `pokemon` in `sub_menu_input`.

Comment: But am I not calling in my method with the args it requires so shouldn't it be taking it in?

Comment: I don't know what you just said. There's no variable called `pokemon` in `sub_menu_input`. `sub_menu_input` takes no parameters. It's not clear where you think it should be "taking it in" from; there's only one `pokemon` reference in the code you posted, and it's local to the `pokemon_array.each` block.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
character = PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon.all[user_input.to_i - 1]
print_pokemon_details(pokemon)  
                    # ^^^^^^^ pokemon not defined
```

You probably meant:

```
pokemon = PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon.all[user_input.to_i - 1]
^^^^^^^
print_pokemon_details(pokemon)
```

Comment: Yup this is what I saw as I re-read through the sub_menu again and looks at why it wasnt defined